# C - Doubly Linked List add new node gives run-time error

Tags: c, data-structures, runtime-error, doubly-linked-list

So I have the following code for a doubly linked list which worked well for the singly linked list. When I try to add a new node using the function addFirst at the beginning of the node, it gives me a run-time error when I have this one line present (commented one). Otherwise, the function worked for a singly linked list and does not give error without that line.

```
void addFirst(DblList *lstPtr, int data)
{
  Node *newNodePtr = (Node *) malloc(sizeof (Node));
  if (newNodePtr == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to allocate new node\n");
    return;
  }
  newNodePtr->data = data;
  newNodePtr->next = NULL;
  newNodePtr->prev = NULL;
  if(lstPtr->nodeCount == 0){
    lstPtr->head = newNodePtr;
    lstPtr->tail = newNodePtr;
  }
  else{
    newNodePtr->next = lstPtr->head;
    lstPtr->head->prev = newNodePtr; //this is the toubling line
    lstPtr->head = newNodePtr;
  }
  lstPtr->nodeCount++;
}
```

Here are the user-defined types-

```
typedef struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
  struct Node *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct DblList {
  struct Node *head;
  struct Node *tail;
  int nodeCount;
} DblList;

void initList(DblList *lstPtr)
{
  lstPtr->head = NULL;
  lstPtr->tail = NULL;
  int nodeCount = 0;
}
```

Edit- It seems to be a segmentation fault but I am not sure.

Comment: `int nodeCount = 0;` --> `lstPtr->nodeCount = 0;`

Comment: Thanks a ton! That seems to have solved the issue. I dunno how I missed that.